# set webpack only to compile files

Tags: webpack

I have old js script that need improvements. I want to write code in es6 style with babeljs compile it to es5 standard with minify in wepback3. How to set webpack to only parse files, save them in another dir and not bundle them?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is, by definition, a module *bundler* - while it might be possible to use plugins to hack it into doing a file-by-file copy, I wouldn't advise it.

Instead, use the [Babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) directly - it will individual files or entire directories depending on what you pass into it. It also has a `--minfied` option that will minify the output for you, without having to manually pipe the files into UglifyJS.

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir build --minified
```